# Check active state of gameObject in List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 4 gameObjects in a List. I would like to check the count of active gameObjects from this list. As in if two gameObjects are active, that means count is 2. How would be the best way to get the count?

```
public List<GameObject> Total_GO;

public void Start()
{
  //Get Count of active gameObjects
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [Linq `Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count) and as a filter use [`GameObject.activeInHierarchy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeInHierarchy.html) or [`GameObject.activeSelf`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-activeSelf.html) according to your needs

```
using System.Linq;

...

void Start()
{
                             // or obj.activeSelf according to your needs
    var activeCount = Total_GO.Count(obj => obj.activeInHierarchy);

    Debug.Log($"Active objects: {activeCount}", this);
}
```

or if you rather want to actually **use** the active objects use [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)

```
 void Start()
{
                         // or obj.activeSelf according to your needs
    var activeObjects = Total_GO.Where(obj => obj.activeInHierarchy).ToList();
                             
    var activeCount = activeObjects.Count;
    Debug.Log($"Active objects: {activeCount}", this);

    foreach(var obj in activeObjects)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```