# check list of gameobject has active gameobject and insert into other list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i have a list of gameobject and I would like to check if each of those is currently active in the scene. The following is my code.

```
foreach (GameObject hazard in SceneHazard)
{
    //Check if hazard exist in the scene
    Debug.Log(hazard.name);

    if (hazard.activeInHierarchy)
    {
        Debug.Log(" is active");
        allActiveHazard.Add(hazard);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(" is NOT active");
    }
}
```

I also found other solution, which I've applied: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65934000/9425428 which would then be something like this:

```
allActiveHazard = SceneHazard.Where(obj => obj.activeInHierarchy).ToList();
```

but I still only get around two gameobjects inside the new list.

[Variables assignment in inspector, the two list on the bottom are private](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kcd5F.png)

[Active gameobjects in hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuXTp.png)

[Console, somehow some gameobjects weren't checked?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvneJ.png)

Am I missing anything here? There are no other inactive parents from the screenshot provided

Comment: Unlike `GameObject.activeSelf`, `GameObject.activeInHierarchy` also checks if any parent GameObjects affect the GameObject’s currently active state. I would check with `activeSelf`

Comment: @rustyBucketBay Ive tried that but to no avail.

Comment: Can you make sure you have errors enabled in the console? Is it possible that the loop is interiores by some exception like e.g. the `allActiveHazard` not initialized? Also the amount of objects is quite limited .. have you tried simply [Debugging your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) step by step with breakpoints?

Comment: @derHugo yes i did. im thinking of adding some delay before assigning the list. the gameobject weren't created by me, probably my colleague added some animation or something similar..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a few seconds delay before assigning the list. Probably somebody added animation to the `GameObject`.

```
StartCoroutine(Delay());

...
...

IEnumerator Delay()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    allActiveHazard = SceneHazard.Where(obj => obj.activeSelf).ToList();
}
```

Btw, I edited my code in response to @derHugo comment because I made some typos previously. Assigning inside the coroutine

Comment: Your code does **not** delay anything at all ... `StartCoroutine` is a non blocking call .. it doesn't delay the method that calls it ....